# XML Files and receiving them without headers

Tags: c#, xml

The company receives a form of XML files and stores them on an S3 bucket, the information is then shown on a customers website.

Issue I am having is they have onboarded a new customer with a new feed. The customers feed which they are now sending me are correct, Although their XML files are missing the declaration at the top.

Example of Declaration missing

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

This is stopping the feed from processing and displaying on the website.

If I manually add the Declaration and re upload it works.

Now the customer is saying they have never had the headers and it works for other 3rd party companies.

Is there a way to add the header once receiving the files, the feed processor & FTP server are in c#, dotnet3.1

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty, new XmlQualifiedName("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") });

        object retVal = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

        // using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(objectXml))
        // using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
        {
            retVal = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            return (T)retVal;
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument xdoc)
    {
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty, new XmlQualifiedName("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") });

        object retVal = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xdoc.ToString()))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
        {
            retVal = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            return (T)retVal;
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string objectXml)
    {
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty, new XmlQualifiedName("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") });

        object retVal = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(objectXml))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
        {
            retVal = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            return (T)retVal;
        }
    }

    // public static T Deserialize<T>(string objectXml, string xmlNamespace)
    // {
    //     var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty, new XmlQualifiedName("xs", xmlNamespace) });

    //     object retVal = null;
    //     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    //     var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    //     settings.IgnoreComments = true;
    //     settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
    //     settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

    //     using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(objectXml))
    //     using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
    //     {

    //         retVal = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    //         return (T)retVal;
    //     }
    // }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream xmlStream)
    {
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty, new XmlQualifiedName("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") });

        object retVal = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, settings))
        {

            retVal = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            return (T)retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public static class XmlUtil
{
    public static string SerializeToString<T>(T value)
    {
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

        using (var stream = new StringWriter())
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
        {
            // This adds our DocType
            writer.WriteDocType("propertyList", null, "http://reaxml.realestate.com.au/propertyList.dtd", null);

            serializer.Serialize(writer, value, emptyNamespaces);
            return stream.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string SerializeToStringUTF8<T>(T value)
    {
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

        using (var stream = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8))
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
        {
            // This adds our DocType
            writer.WriteDocType("propertyList", null, "http://reaxml.realestate.com.au/propertyList.dtd", null);

            serializer.Serialize(writer, value, emptyNamespaces);
            return stream.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As the why they generate without the headers we can only speculate, you would have to ask them.  Probably they are generating the files manually in code and not using a XML library to create them.  Also asking multiple questions might get your question closed, so you may want to take that out

Comment: Thanks for that, 

Removed the second question.

Yes they are generating it through code, I asked the vendor. 

There response was rather simple, 

"Everyone else's system can understand it, so make yours"

Comment: XML prolog is optional. It would be good to build your systems to work with and without a prolog. Can you share your code that fails to read the XML without a prolog?

Comment: If the XML can't be processed when the header is absent, then there's something wrong with the way it is being processed: XML says the header (technically the "XML declaration") is optional. Rather than trying to bend the XML to fit, you should fix the way you are parsing it.

Comment: The Net library requires the header when using the Document class.  You can parse using the Element Class instead when you do not have the header.

Comment: @jdweng that's not true, the declaration is optional. You can quite easily [test your claim](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gQsDNA).

Comment: As others have noted the prologue is optional, so we need to see a [mcve] showing how you are parsing the XML -- specifically the code that throws an error when the prologue is missing.  With that we could advise how to fix the code so that it no longer fails in the absence of the prologue.   See: [ask].

Comment: I am by no means a C# or.net developer in anyway, it is very foreign to me 

I believe I have found the parsing statement. I will past it above.

Comment: Do you know which of the `Deserialize<T>` methods above is failing?  Might you be able to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?

Comment: I added the strings above. in regards to which one is failing i do not know, 

As it does process them and store them. but does not display them.

They dont actually fail, just do not read any XML data.